# What song did Avraham ben Avraham sing before he was killed?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, song-poetry

Avraham ben Avraham or Count Valentine Potocki, converted to Judaism and was burned at the stake for doing so by the Roman Catholic Church. Before he was killed he sang a song that was later used in the Volozhin yeshiva and by Rabbi Isser Zalman Meltzer after Yom Kippur. Does anyone know what song he sang?

More Information about Avraham ben Avraham here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_Abraham

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Wikipedia article on the Ger Tzedek is constantly "adjusted" by Polish people who cannot accept that it ever happened. I have tried to include scholarly work, for instance by Dr. S Leiman, and it generally gets deleted or minimized quickly. Don't trust the article much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Strange Side of Jewish History writes:](http://strangeside.com/convert-avraham-the-convert-of-vilna)

Rav Avrohom went on his last way with dancing and joy. In Volozhin Yeshiva bochurim used to sing with wonderful deveikus the words of the Ger Tzedek’s song taken from the beginning of davening: “But we are Your nation the sons of Your covenant, the sons of Avrohom Your beloved one, to whom You swore at Mount Moriah, the seed of Yitzchok his only son who was bound upon the altar, etc. Blessed are You, etc., who sanctifies His name in the multitudes.”

In
אבל אנחנו עמך בני בריתך בני אברהם אוהבך שנשבעת לו בהר המוריה, זרע יצחק יחידך שנעקד על גבי מזבחך, עדת יעקב בנך בכורך, שמאהבתך שאהבת אותו ומשמחתך  קראת אותו ישראל וישורון
לפיכך אנו חיבין להודות לך ולשבחך ולפארך וליתן שבח והודאה לשמך. וחיבין אנו לומר לפניך בכל יום ערב ובוקר שמע ישראל ה' אלהינו ה' אחד. אשרנו מה טוב חלקנו, מה נעים גורלנו, מה יפה ירושתנו אשרנו שאנו משכימין ומעריבין בכל יום תמיד ערב ובוקר ואומרים שמע ישראל ה' אלהינו ה' אחד.
אתה הוא קודם שנברא העולם אתה הוא אחר שנברא העולם, אתה הוא בעולם הזה ואתה הוא לעולם הבא, אתה הוא ראשון ואתה הוא אחרון. קדש שמך הגדול והקדוש בעולמך, ובישועתך תרום ותגביה קרננו. ברוך... המקדש שמו ברבים.

You can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BltSEWUvvU&ab_channel=Yiddishetaam).

Comment: Amen, great answer